# How to fix InMobi error when putting test mode off

Tags: android, ads, inmobi

When I'm in test mode, I can load rewarded video on inMobi but when I put test mode off I'm getting this error:

```
Please check the site status on InMobi dashboard or reach out to Partner Manager
```

what is the cause of problem?

Comment: @Abhi did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no i give up InMobi

Comment: @tamtoum1987 which network now you use i face the same problem other than google adMob